# How to convert this to parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, oledb, oledbconnection

I don't have any ideas about parameters, I'm making date time records my database is only Microsoft Access 2010. How can I switch my codes to the parameters?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
            string EmployeeTimeEnrtyMapping;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        sb.Append("INSERT INTO TimeEntryTimeSheet (");
        sb.Append("CutoffId,");
        sb.Append("EmployeeId,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs1,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs2,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs3,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs4,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs5,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs6,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs7,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs8,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs9,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs10,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs11,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs12,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs13,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs14,");
        sb.Append("Dayhrs15,");

        sb.Append("DayhrsOT1,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT2,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT3,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT4,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT5,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT6,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT7,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT8,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT9,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT10,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT11,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT12,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT13,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT14,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsOT15,");

        sb.Append("DayhrsHol1,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol2,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol3,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol4,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol5,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol6,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol7,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol8,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol9,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol10,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol11,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol12,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol13,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol14,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHol15,");

        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT1,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT2,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT3,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT4,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT5,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT6,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT7,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT8,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT9,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT10,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT11,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT12,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT13,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT14,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsHolOT15,");

        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol1,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol2,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol3,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol4,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol5,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol6,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol7,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol8,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol9,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol10,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol11,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol12,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol13,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol14,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHol15,");

        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT1,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT2,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT3,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT4,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT5,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT6,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT7,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT8,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT9,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT10,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT11,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT12,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT13,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT14,");
        sb.Append("DayhrsSHolOT15,");

        sb.Append("CreatedDate)");
        sb.Append("VALUES(");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.TimeRangeRowId + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.EmployeeId + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day7 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.Day15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay7 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.OtDay15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol7 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayHol15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT7 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsHolOT15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol7 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHol15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT1 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT2 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT3 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT4 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT5 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT6 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT8 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT9 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT10 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT11 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT12 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT13 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT14 + "',");
        sb.Append("'" + timeEntry.DayhrsSHolOT15 + "',");

        sb.Append("'" + DateTime.Now + "')");

        EmployeeTimeEnrtyMapping = sb.ToString();

        ClassConnectionDb.ExecuteNonQuery(EmployeeTimeEnrtyMapping, CommandType.Text);
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @HeiSciff Have a read of the link I provided - it shows the basic pattern you want to follow. It will have types like `SqlCommand` etc. You will change them to `OleDbCommand` etc. But otherwise, the pattern is much the same.

Answer (score -1):

I would select the data out of your access database and try to put it into a list.

This is how you create a list of strings.

```
List<string> ListOfStrings = new List<string>();
```

And this is how you add items to a list.

```
ListOfStrings.Add(StringVar)
```

This might give you an idea on how to do it.
[How to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148656/10911782)

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear what is your goal.  If you are trying to create/insert a set of records, on a repeated basis - - that will not have any data in them.... it's generally not a good design concept.

Having said that - one approach to it is to manually set up a table that serves as the model.  Then insert the model table using an append query.